# Can't read keys from App.config

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, app-config

I want to read some values from my project's App.config file, but when I do this:

```
var appsettings = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
```

I only get four entries: `StopTestRunCallTimeoutInSeconds`, `LogSizeLimitInMegs`, `CreateTraceListener` and `GetCollectorDataTimeout`, which aren't even listed in the XML. My keys `username` and `password` do not even appear.

My App.Config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="username" value="Administrator" />
    <add key="password" value="password" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Am I missing something? It seems to me like I was reading from a totally different config file, but there is no other one.

Comment: if you put a break point on appSettings and you hover it when it stop, do you see some keys? because I tried on my own and I saw all your keys.

Comment: appSettings only shows the four entries I mentioned above. none of mine. 
And don't worry the username and password written to the config file are just for test purposes, nothing final.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the solution! The problem was, that I debugged a unit test, which was located in a different sub-project within the same solution. I copied the app.config file to the same project as the unit test and it works fine now. thanks for your help!

Comment: I was stuck until i found your solution. Thanks.. :)

Comment: glad to hear one of my first answers on SO is still helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

you can read your application settings by pulling them by name

```
var username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"]
var password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"]
```

The underlying data type of AppSettings is NameValueCollection. So you pull the value based on the key.

Here is the documentation for AppSettings which shows an example
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're reading from the QTAgentService.exe.config instead of your app.config.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff934570.aspx

Comment: Did I possibly miss to configure something, after adding the config file via visual studio? Or how can I change this?

Comment: I can't find the QTAgentService.exe.config XML it's not as described at `<drive letter:>\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\.` it must be something else

Comment: Is it possible, that a different config file is beeing used for debugging?